# Come posso sintetizzare questo concetto con una sola parola?

Tags: word-choice

Esiste una parola che esprima il concetto di "architettato alla perfezione", "matematicamente studiato"?

Comment: Benvenuto to Italian.SE! Penso che un po' più di contesto possa aiutare a dare risposta alla tua domanda.

Comment: Una possibilità - anche se, come osserva giustamente @Charo, dipende dal contesto - potrebbe essere *cesellato*. Ma parlando ad es. di un piano d'azione, ho sentito usare anche l'aggettivo *blindato* (nel senso di *a tutta prova*, che esprime il concetto che cerchi per implicazione).

Comment: "Infallibile" come suggerito mi pare ottimo, forse anche "resiliente" può essere valido

Answer (score 7):

Sì, esiste, manca effettivamente il contesto, ma se dovessi sintetizzare qualcosa di "architettato alla perfezione" direi "infallibile" ovvero senza alcuna possibilità di fallire.

Infallibile può riferirsi ad un piano:

*"Questo è un piano infallibile"*

Oppure a una speciale dote di qualcuno:

*"La sua mira è infallibile"*

Il concetto che tenti di esprimere sembra qualcosa con scarse possibilità di fallire...

Qualcosa che essendo matematicamente studiato o progettato non è facile che "vada storto"